# An issue with scanf() in Visual Studio Code (C)

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-code

So I have this piece of code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    int i;
    printf("What's your number?\n");
    scanf("%d", i);

    return 0;
}
```

Everytime I try to run it in the output, I don't see anything and it doesn't try to take my input, it looks something like this

```
[Running] cd "c:\Users\bauti\Downloads\ENGG-1410\" && gcc Assignment_1.c -o Assignment_1 && "c:\Users\bauti\Downloads\ENGG-1410\"Assignment_1
```

with nothing else.

Since I'm using Code Runner, I decided to go **File -> Preferences -> Settings -> Code-runner: Run in terminal**, to try and run my code through the terminal, but when I do that, I get this message:

```
$ cd "c:\Users\bauti\Downloads\ENGG-1410\" && gcc Assignment_1.c -o Assignment_1 && "c:\Users\bauti\Downloads\ENGG-1410\"Assignment_1
bash: cd: c:\Users\bauti\Downloads\ENGG-1410" && gcc Assignment_1.c -o Assignment_1 && c:UsersbautiDownloadsENGG-1410"Assignment_1: No such file or directory
```

and my code doesn't execute. So now I am confused as to what I'm supposed to do. I even tried to add the VSCode bin path to the path environment variable, but still no solution. If anyone can try and help me out, it'd be appreciated.

Comment: `scanf("%d", i);` -> `scanf("%d", &i);`

Comment: In C everything is passed by value - a function receives a COPY of the thing you pass.  If you write a C function that takes a parameter and then tries to update the parameter you need to pass a pointer to the thing - a COPY of the pointer is passed to the function but it still points to the same place so the content of the pointer can be updated.  So for scanf you want `i` updated and that means you need to pass a pointer.

Comment: When running in terminal you have a misplaced quote: `"c:\Users\bauti\Downloads\ENGG-1410\"Assignment_1`, it should be at the end, after the `1`. As it is, the `\ ` before it is treated as a special character, whose meaning is "keep the following `"` as it is". Which is why `\"` is replaced by `"`, and obviously the file doesn't exist.

Comment: Learn how to się scanf

Comment: @JerryJeremiah But the error message mentions `ENGG-1410"Assignment_1`, where the backslash has disappeared, which clearly isn't intentional

Comment: Ahhh.  So  the backslashes need to all be escaped - none of them show up in the name of the file in the error message.  The thing should be `cd "c:\\Users\\bauti\\Downloads\\ENGG-1410\\" && gcc Assignment_1.c -o Assignment_1 && "c:\\Users\\bauti\\Downloads\\ENGG-1410\\Assignment_1"` so that all the backslashes show up.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I tried passing i in as a pointer but I'm still getting the same thing.

Comment: @FabiosaysReinstateMonica so the reason as to why im getting this issue is because there's a file that doesn't exist?

Comment: You have 2 different issues. One is the wrong `scanf` (as Eugene said, you must use `&i`). But the compiler should give you a warning there. Instead, you are not getting it. And maybe you are not even compiling anything (have you tried to compile a completely wrong program, and verify that you get some error messages?). To solve this second issue, which has to do with how you call the compiler, you have to check the exact string that is passed to it. I think Jerry is right, you need to escape all the backslashes. If you don't, the path is wrong, resulting in "No such file or directory"

Comment: @FabiosaysReinstateMonica how would I escape all the backslashes?

Comment: You must edit the string that is taken by Code Runner and passed to the compiler: it must be as Jerry wrote, with double backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    printf("What's your number?\n");
    scanf("%d",&i); // & operator was missing
    printf("Number was:%d",i);
    return 0;
}
```